# Firestore changes are not synced with stream builder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

When I update the database in console or app, the changes are not synced in the app. I thought it's because of orderBy and indexing settings, but commenting them didn't help. What's wrong with my code? How to set up auto-sync?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerMenu(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Заявки'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('orders')
            .where('companyId', isEqualTo: globals.companyId)
            // .orderBy('dateAdded', descending: true)
            // .orderBy('statusId')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return LoadingScreen();
            default:
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Items(
                              order: snapshot.data.documents[index],
                            ),
                          )),
                      child: OrderCard(
                        order: snapshot.data.documents[index],
                      )));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are just getting the snapshot as a stream once, but to get the actual changes when you modify in console or app you need to make a subscription to the stream. You need to .listen the stream of data so that you get notified when something change.

Also you may want to separate the logic of firebase its easier.

For example:

Create a Stream Controller:

```
final StreamController<DataType> _streamController = StreamController<DataType>();
```

Listen to firebase data and add it to stream:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .where('companyId', isEqualTo: globals.companyId)
        .snapshots().listen((DocumentSnapshot snapShot){
          _streamController.add(snapShot.documents);
        });
```

Now you can listen to the stream from stream controller:

```
_streamController.stream;
```

Comment: how to create a Stream Controller with Null Safety?

Comment: Null Safety changes a lot of things we are used to like this. :(

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it's necessary to add custom indexes in firestore console when a query consists of .where().orderBy and so on.